# Flutter - Firebase Dynamic Link not Working while app is in kill mode

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I have integrated Firebase Dynamic link in my Flutter application to open and navigate application users to specific screen in app.

For that first of all I have added below plugin in pubspec.yaml file:

```
firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.5
```

Then, I have created a separate class to handle related stuffs as below:

```
  class DynamicLinkService {
  late BuildContext context;

  FirebaseDynamicLinks dynamicLinks = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;

  Future<void> initDynamicLinks(BuildContext context) async {
    this.context = context;
    dynamicLinks.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {
      var dynamicLink=dynamicLinkData.link.toString();
      if (dynamicLink.isNotEmpty &&
          dynamicLink.startsWith(ApiConstants.baseUrl) &&
          dynamicLink.contains("?")) {
          //Getting data here and navigating...
          ...
          ...
          ...
      } 
    }).onError((error) {
      print("This is error >>> "+error.message);
    });
  }
}
```

Now, I am initialising Deep-link as below in my home_screen:

```
final DynamicLinkService _dynamicLinkService = DynamicLinkService();
```

and then calling below method in `initState()`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await _dynamicLinkService.initDynamicLinks(context);
    });
  }
```

*This is working like a charm!* **when** my application is in recent mode or in background mode.

**But the issue is** when the application is **closed/Killed**, clicking on dynamic link just open the app but could not navigate.

What might be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone please answer this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me answer my own question, It might be useful for someone!

So, In above code I forgot to add code to handle dynamic link while the app is in closed/kill mode.

We need to add this code separately:

```
//this is when the app is in closed/kill mode
final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
if (initialLink != null) {
  handleDynamicLink(initialLink);
}
```

So, final code looks like as below:

```
//this is when the app is in closed/kill mode
final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
if (initialLink != null) {
  handleDynamicLink(initialLink);
}

//this is when the app is in recent/background mode
dynamicLinks.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {
  handleDynamicLink(dynamicLinkData);
}).onError((error) {
  print("This is error >>> "+error.message);
});
```

Its working like a charm now! That's All.

Comment: I am stuck here too but my code looks like yours. Could you tell me how your CFBundleURLSchemes looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your CFBundleURLSchemes in info.plist is set to your app bundle Id as that is the default for firebase dynamic links for some that this answer doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).